# How do I run python program in background and close the ssh terminal?

Tags: linux, python, raspberry-pi

I've wrote a python program to read data from serial and write in the file. Used raspberryPi with raspbian OS. I can run program in foreground successfully without any issue it is writing the data in file. But when I use '&' "./ReadFromMeter&" to put it in background it doesn't write anything in the file. checked status using $ps -ux it's showing stat S means suspend but when use $jobs command it shows running. tried to change nice value but no success. output of $ps -ux

```
pi        1461  0.0  0.4   8724  4000 pts/1    Ss   12:57   0:01 -bash
pi        2177  3.1  0.8  15720  8480 pts/1    S    15:21   0:00 python3 ./CodeForMeter.py
pi        2179  0.0  0.2   9788  2500 pts/1    R+   15:21   0:00 ps -ux
```

output of jobs

```
[1]+  Running                 ./CodeForMeter.py &
```

Tried:-

```
using linux nohup.

Like this nohup python /Full/path/CodeForMeter.py&
Tried adding full path of output file also.
```

Comment: Actually I tried debugging using print statement it's running very well but not writing anything in the file. Do I need to create an Interrupt to write the data in file after every second?

Comment: It was programming error. Solved the issues by putting file.flush() in particular place and closing file properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`nohup python program.py > /path/of/choice/program.log &`

It will run the code in background and print all output to the file `program.log`.